# With Protobuf-net, does it allow deserialization reuse existing instances if they are the same?

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net

I'm using Protobuf-net. Suppose I have a list of Gizmo objects serialized and that each gizmo object reference a Gazoo object. The Gazoo object might be the same object referred by several Gizmo objects.

How would deserialization work in this situation?

Would I get more than one copies of Gazoos for the same referred one in the gizmo objects?

What I would expect would be one copy of Gazoo for all the duplicates in the serialized data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wire-format defined by google is a *tree* serializer, not a *graph* serializer, so object-references are **not** preserved. However, once I get "v2" shipped, I have some nefarious plans to hack object-reference/graph support into the model - essentially by (in that mode) including additional object-id data. This *will* make it somewhat tricky to use in interop scenarios, however - so ideally only good for protobuf-net <===> protobuf-net.

But nothing today - you'll get multiple copies, or if you get a circular reference it should explode.

---

As an update: ***this is now available*** in protobuf-net v2, but as an implementation-specific feature *outside* of the code spec.

Comment: @stecey this is now available, btw

Comment: @marc-gravell, how can I use it? Should I use special attributes? objA.Ref = objB; objB.Ref = objA; - this scenario doensn't work for me for now. protobuf-net version: 2.0.0.470.

Comment: @Rover you need to mark the property with `AsReference=true` in the [ProtoMember], or (if you don't want to use the attributes) you can do it via the RuntimeTypeModel instead. You can also specifiy this as the default for all properties of a given type, via either the [ProtoContract], or again via the RuntimeTypeModel

Comment: @MarcGravell Any example of how this can be done via the RuntimeTypeModel API?  I can't see anything obvious hanging off of it or the different "Add" fields API.

Comment: @kdawg there is a second Add (AddField perhaps?) which returns the ValueMember. You want AsReference.